# Calculating sigmoid value of a bigdecimal in java

Tags: java

question here and would be greatly appreciated if you could help.

I am trying to calculate the sigmoid value of a bigdecimal using something along the lines of this code that I use for double values

```
double a = 1 / (1 + Math.exp("a"));
```

However I would like to perform the same operation for the bigdecimal datatype but I cannot find code that will do this for a bigdecimal

```
Math.exp(x)
```

Is there any short piece of code that would provide this sigmoid value on a bigdecimal

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at Bayesian MCMC [BigDecimalUtils.exp()](http://code.google.com/p/beast-mcmc/source/browse/trunk/src/dr/math/BigDecimalUtils.java?r=3502) which uses [Taylor's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem).

```
BigDecimal exponential = BigDecimalUtils.exp(BigDecimal.valueOf(3.2), 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can approximate the exponential function `Math.exp(x)` using the Taylor/Maclaurin series expansion:

`exp(x) = sum_n=0^infinity x^n / (n!)` which is equal to:

`exp(x) = 1 + x + (x^2)/2! + (x^3)/3! + (x^4)/4! + ...`

Although this is a sum of infinitely many terms, you can stop after the first few terms to get an approximate solution, although the more terms you add, the closer the answer will be.

In the expression above, `x!` means the factorial of `x`: `x! = x * (x - 1) * (x - 2) * ... * 1`

All of the necessary operations (`add`, `divide`, `pow`) are defined for `BigDecimal`.

*EDIT*: It turns out the Sigmoid Function has its own [Maclaurin series approximation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SigmoidFunction.html):

`1/(1 + exp(-x)) = 1/2 + 1/4 * x - 1/48 * x^3 + 1/480 x^5 - ...`

Comment: Sorry thats even more confusing for me :( - can you explain it in english terminolgy or provide some functional java code? I dont know what sum_n=0^infinity x^n / (n!) means. Thanks, Martin