# How can I calculate high precision double value use java in Machine learning?

Tags: java, machine-learning, double, precision, logistic-regression

I was using **Logistic regression** to train my data.
In this process, I need calculate a **sigmoid function** coded like:

```
private double sigmoid(double x) {
    return 1.0 / (1 + Math.pow(Math.E, -1 * x));
}
```

So if my `x` is large than 36, it always return `1.0`, and I will get `Infinity` in `log(1 - sigmoid(x))`.

I guess java is not a good language at machine-learning, I just need apply in this project.

I also know Java's precision principle through this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43542063/addition-of-very-small-double-values-java), But I still want to know is there anyway to solve this problem.

Comment: Consider using `BigDecimal` for high precision values. Also this question may be helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784056/calculating-sigmoid-value-of-a-bigdecimal-in-java

Comment: "I know java is not a good language" - ignorant statement.

Comment: This is floating point specific (not language specific). One trick is to use a different scale, say a logarithmic one or such - if possible. Here probably not.

Comment: sorry, my meaning is java maybe is not good at machine-learning.

Answer (score 1):

While it is a precision issue, usually the way to deal with exploding gradients and ensure numerical stability is to clip the input of the function:

```
final double CLIP = 30d;
input = Math.min(CLIP, Math.max(-CLIP, input)));
return 1.0 / (1.0 + Math.exp(-input))
```

You can also clip the output to [0, 1]:

```
double output = 1.0 / (1.0 + Math.exp(-input))
return Math.min(0d, Math.max(1d, output)));
```

Comment: I am not sure if I am understanding correctly, sigmoid function always return value between 0 and 1, so it can't do any change. Do your meaning is like `Math.min(CLIP, Math.max(-CLIP, input))` ?

Comment: true, sigmoid output can be clipped between 0 and 1, or the input can be clipped with a higher decimal.

Answer (score 0):

this works perfectly for me

tested 20 , 40 , 49

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.MathContext;

/**
 *
 * @author tawfik
 */
public class Mathic {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       BigDecimal sigmoid = sigmoid(37);
        System.out.println(sigmoid);
    }
    static private BigDecimal sigmoid(double x) {
    return new BigDecimal(1.0).divide(new BigDecimal(1).add(new BigDecimal(Math.pow(Math.E, -1 * x))),MathContext.DECIMAL128);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways of writing the sigmoid function that are more [numerically stable](http://timvieira.github.io/blog/post/2014/02/11/exp-normalize-trick/)

```
private double sigmoid(double x) {
    if (x > 0) {
        return 1.0 / (1 + Math.exp(-x));
    }
    else {
        z = Math.exp(x);
        return z / (1 + z);
    }
}
```